# column values in a row

Tags: string, oracle11g, oracle11gr1

I have following table

```
    id    count   hour   age   range
    -------------------------------------
    0       5       10     61     10-200
    1       6       20     61     10-200
    2       7       15     61     10-200  
    5       9       5      61     201-300
    7       10      25     61     201-300
    0       5       10     62     10-20
    1       6       20     62     10-20
    2       7       15     62     10-20  
    5       9       5      62     21-30
    1       8       6      62     21-30
    7       10      25     62     21-30
    10      15      30     62     31-40
```

I need to select distinct values of column range
I tried following query

```
Select distinct range as interval from table name where age  = 62;
```

its result is in a column as follows:

```
interval
----------
10-20
21-30
31-41
```

How can I get result as follows?

```
10-20, 21-30, 31-40
```

EDITED:
I am now trying following query:

```
select sys_connect_by_path(range,',') interval
from
    (select distinct NVL(range,'0') range , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RANGE) rn 

 from table_name where age = 62)

 where connect_by_isleaf = 1 CONNECT BY rn = PRIOR rn+1 start with rn = 1;
```

Which is giving me output as:

```
Interval
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
, 10-20,10-20,10-20,21-30,21-30, 31-40
```

guys plz help me to get my desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on 11.2 rather than just 11.1, you can use the `LISTAGG` aggregate function

```
SELECT listagg( interval, ',' ) 
         WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY interval )
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT range AS interval
          FROM table_name
         WHERE age = 62)
```

If you are using an earlier version of Oracle, you could use one of the other [Oracle string aggregation techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php) on Tim Hall's page.  Prior to 11.2, my personal preference would be to create a [user-defined aggregate function](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php#user_defined_aggregate_function) so that you can then

```
SELECT string_agg( interval )
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT range AS interval
              FROM table_name
             WHERE age = 62)
```

If you don't want to create a function, however, you can use the [ROW_NUMBER and SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH approach](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php#row_number) though that tends to get a bit harder to follow

```
with x as (
  SELECT DISTINCT range AS interval
          FROM table_name
         WHERE age = 62 )
select ltrim( max( sys_connect_by_path(interval, ','))
                keep (dense_rank last order by curr),
              ',') range
  from (select interval,
               row_number() over (order by interval) as curr,
               row_number() over (order by interval) -1 as prev
          from x)
connect by prev = PRIOR curr
  start with curr = 1
```

Comment: no i m using 11.1 its not supprorting listagg and concatenate functions.

Comment: @Pramod - Updated my answer with pre-11.2 functionality