# How to retrieve two columns data in A,B format in Oracle

Tags: string, oracle

I have two columns in oracle database

```
+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 |
+---------+---------+
| A       | 1       |
| A       | 2       |
+---------+---------+
```

I want to retireive the data like i will get data as result

```
+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 |
+---------+---------+  
| A       | 1,2     |
+---------+---------+
```

Please provide me the solution.

Comment: I've edited your question to see lines in code mode, can you confirm that's what you meant... Oops, bluefeet trumped my edits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [column values in a row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482560/column-values-in-a-row)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building a comma-separated list of values in an Oracle SQL statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822700/building-a-comma-separated-list-of-values-in-an-oracle-sql-statement)

Comment: "Please provide me the solution." nice one

Answer (score 20):

Tim Hall has a pretty canonical list of [string aggregation techniques in Oracle](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).

Which technique you use depends on a number of factors including the version of Oracle and whether you are looking for a purely SQL solution.  If you are using Oracle 11.2, I'd probably suggest using `LISTAGG`

```
SELECT column1, listagg( column2, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP( order by column2 )
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY column1
```

If you are using an earlier version of Oracle, assuming you don't need a purely SQL solution, I would generally prefer using the [user-defined aggregate function](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php#user_defined_aggregate_function) approach.

Comment: Justin, would this query work if we need to group by on multiple columns please?Thanks.

Comment: @Jimmy - Yes, it should.

Comment: Additional details at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm#SQLRF55593

Answer (score 4):

**All abow answers are correct** and I want to add one case to solve small problem. In my case `my_column1` type was `nvarchar2` but text was `number` and the bellow code does not work and display me only whitespace:

```
select group_id, listagg( t.my_column1 || '-' || to_char(t.doc_date,'dd.mm.yyyy') ||  ' ') within group(order by doc_date) 
 from my_table t
 group by group_id
```

when I wrote like this it works.

```
select group_id, listagg( to_char(t.my_column1) || '-' || to_char(t.doc_date,'dd.mm.yyyy') ||  ' ') within group(order by doc_date) 
 from my_table t
 group by group_id
```

I hope my feedback would save someone's time

Answer (score 3):

If you have got 10g, then you have to go through the function below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_comma_separated_value (input_val  in  number)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  return_text  VARCHAR2(10000) := NULL;
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT col2 FROM table_name WHERE col1 = input_val) LOOP
    return_text := return_text || ',' || x.col2 ;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN LTRIM(return_text, ',');
END;
/
```

So, you can do like:

```
select col1, get_comma_separated_value(col1) from table_name
```

[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0eb31/2)

If you have got oracle 11g, you can use [listagg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) :

```
SELECT 
    col1,
    LISTAGG(col2, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col2) "names"
FROM table_x
GROUP BY col1
```

[Fiddle here for Listagg](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1b6a/2)

For mysql, its gonna be simple:

```
SELECT col1, GROUP_CONCAT(col2) FROM table_name GROUP BY col1
```

Answer (score 2):

On my oracle version 10 it do the job:

```
SELECT column1, wm_concat( column2)
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY column1
```