# Oracle group by only ONE column - update

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by

I am stuck in similar situation as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919957/oracle-group-by-only-one-column).
I have multiple columns with different types of data, and I want to select all columns but **group by** it with only one column.

My Table:

```
+--------+----------+----------+-------+-----------------------+
| id     | b_group  | col2     | col3  |       col4            |
+--------+----------+----------+-------+-----------------------+
| 1      | 1        | abcd     | 100   | www.google.com        |
| 2      | 1        | xyz      | 200   | www.yahoo.com         |
| 3      | 2        | dfs      | 200   | www.stackoverflow.com |
| 4      | 3        | asda3    | 78    | www.imdb.com          |
| 5      | 4        | zsdvf4   | 65    | www.youtube.com       |
| 6      | 5        | sdf4     | 101   | www.ymail.com         |
| 7      | 5        | ssdfsd   | 200   | www.gmail.com         |
| 8      | 1        | zxcgdf4  | 200   | www.club.com          |
| 9      | 6        | yujhgj   | 202   | www.thunderbird.com   |
+--------+----------+----------+-------+-----------------------+
```

After reading the solution provided [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43920159/1860468), what I understood is to use aggregate function so my query is like:

```
select MIN(b_group),id,col2,col3,col4 from myTable where col3='200' group by id,col2,col3,col4;
```

But this is not working in my case, it is giving all the records where col3=200.

My desired Output:

```
+--------+----------+----------+-------+-----------------------+
| id     | b_group  | col2     | col3  |       col4            |
+--------+----------+----------+-------+-----------------------+
| 2      | 1        | xyz      | 200   | www.yahoo.com         |
| 3      | 2        | dfs      | 200   | www.stackoverflow.com |
| 6      | 5        | sdf4     | 200   | www.ymail.com         |
+--------+----------+----------+-------+-----------------------+
```

I don't care which record is picked, order don't matter.
I just want to select all columns with group by only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By applying a `group by` clause, you get a result row per unique combination of all the columns in it (in this case, per unique combination of `id`, `col2`, `col3`, and `col4`). Instead, you could use the `row_number` window function to number rows per `b_group`, and then select just the (arbitrary) first of each group:

```
SELECT id, b_group, col2, col3, col4 
FROM   (SELECT id, b_group, col2, col3, col4,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b_group ORDER BY 1) AS rn
        FROM   mytable                 
        WHERE  col3 = 200)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,
when I ran the above query I got an error **ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression**

so I used `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b_group ORDER BY b_group)` and it worked.

Comment: @niceguy I keep forgetting that `row_number` **requires** an `order by` clause, thanks!. Note that `order by b_group` is meaningless, as all the rows in the same partition will have the same `b_group` anyway. While it's not wrong, it may be a bit confusing to the future reader. In such cases I prefer to dummy it out with something like `order by 1`.