# How to set record in one line after Group By

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I want to set all record in one line with seperated by `,` after GroupBy

**My input:**

```
+ --------- + -------------- +
| Name      | Phone Number   |
+ --------- + -------------- +
| John      | 1234567        |
| John      | 1472583        |
| John      | 3698521        |
| John      | 7896541        |
+ --------- + -------------- +
```

**Output I want**

```
+ --------- + -------------------------------+
| Name      |           Phone Number         |
+ --------- + -------------------------------+
| John      | 1234567,1472583,3698521,7896541|
+ --------- + -------------------------------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve two columns data in A,B format in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145379/how-to-retrieve-two-columns-data-in-a-b-format-in-oracle) and [Concatenate and group multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558509/concatenate-and-group-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [`listagg()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030):

```
select name, listagg(phone_number, ', ') within group (order by phone_number) as phone_numbers
from t
group by name;
```