# PL/SQL Concat Multiple String and their Value

Tags: sql, oracle

The set of data from my current query

| AcctNbr | MIACCTTYPCD | USRFLDCD | VALUE | BAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | VALU | PSMX | Y | 1500 |
| 10001 | VALU | PSOD | 1 | 1500 |
| 10002 | CHK | PSMX | Y | 2000 |
| 10002 | CHK | PSOD | 1 | 2000 |
| 10003 | HPLS | PSMX | Y | 3000 |
| 10003 | HPLS | PSOD | 1 | 3000 |

The result I want to make

| AcctNbr | MIACCTTYPCD | USRFLDCD | VALUE | BAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | VALU | PSMX, PSOD | Y, 1 | 1500 |
| 10002 | CHK | PSMX, PSOD | Y, 1 | 2000 |
| 10003 | HPLS | PSMX, PSOD | Y, 1 | 3000 |

Query:

```
select a.acctnbr, a.MIACCTTYPCD, userfieldcd.USRFLDCD, userfieldcd.value, m.bal as odbal
from table a
left join table h on a.acctnbr = h.acctnbr and h.entity = 'REOD' and h.inactv is null and h.acctentityvalue = 'Y'
left join table b on a.acctnbr = b.acctnbr and b.lastmaint = to_date('2022-08-25','YYYY-MM-DD')
left join table m on a.acctnbr = m.acctnbr and baltypecode = 'MOVD',
(select u.acctnbr, u.USRFLDCD, u.value 
from table u
where u.USRFLDCD in ('PSMX', 'PSOD') 
) USERFIELDCD 
where a.ACCTCD = 'CK'
and a.curracctstatcd = 'ACT'
and m.bal <> 0
and USERFIELDCD.acctnbr = a.acctnbr
order by a.acctnbr;
```

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145379/how-to-retrieve-two-columns-data-in-a-b-format-in-oracle

Comment: It should be something like this then?

LISTAGG(USERFIELDCD.USRFLDCD, ', ') within group (ORDER BY USERFIELDCD.USRFLDCD) as Blah